# Can a wireless router identify "clients" that are within range but NOT connected?

Tags: router, wifi

The results of my searches have not been able to say that it is possible to get a mac address of devices that are within the range of a wireless router.

Can someone confirm whether or not this is actually possible?

To my limited knowledge, the router would be broadcasting information that the "potential" clients can read, meaning the router has no access to any information from the client. What I would like to know is if it is possible to somehow get a reference, or at least a count, to the number of unique devices that have "seen" my router's SSID?

Can you please provide a link to some documentation that can give me a clearer understanding of that, and if it is possible to achieve this using any other hardware device, please feel free to bring it up.

Edit:

The following is practical example of what I would like to achieve:
I would like to have a device (router?) sitting in my store (with whatever special setting up required) and at the end of the day be able to get some statistics related to how many devices were near my store (regardless of whether the devices tried to connect or not). And by number of devices I am "estimating" the number of customers I have had today.

If this is not possible with a regular router, as there any other device that can do this.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @HopelessN00b I want to get a count of devices that CAN access my router (but have not necessarily tried to)

Comment: Right.  And you want to do this for the purposes of...?  In any event, the answer is "any device with a wifi-capable transmitter/receiver can access your wifi router."  There are several billion such devices estimated in existence.  No one's bothered to actually count them all, though.

Comment: @HopelessN00b devices cannot access my router if they are not within its range. The purpose is to get a count (example: of the number of devices at my coffee shop at a given time..) I edited the question to make the "within range" part clearer

Comment: Any clients with active radios using the same frequency (2.4/5GHz) your router uses can be "seen".  Whether your wireless router can identify them or not is a function of that model router's software.

Comment: @jscott what you are saying is that it IS possible (depending on router's software) to identify the devices, even when they are not connected, right? Can you point me to a router model or documentation supporting that please? Thanks

Comment: @7usam If you want a decent answer you need to tell us *what actual, practical problem* you are trying to solve. The answer to your question as stated is "What you want is not possible": Your router is broadcasting on an open radio channel, any shmuck with a 2.4GHz (or 5GHz) receiver can "see" it, and there is absolutely no way for you to know they did unless they make some kind of a broadcast.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the big fuss is here, the asker's question is unambiguous and anyone who has knowledge required to answer his question can recognize and post a useful answer.

Comment: @voretaq7 thanks for that. Edited the question with an "actual, practical problem". All my research says the same as what you are telling me "It isn't possible", so I thought I'd ask to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: @JustinL.: True, but then it won't be a useful or helpful answer. The answer would just be "No, because that includes devices that don't even have a transmitter." Likely he doesn't want to count such devices, but we can't tell without knowing why he needs such a count.

Comment: Indeed, there is all sorts of interesting information is available on the Wifi spectrums. The question has been asked by security experts and crackers and there are security papers which discuss just this. The correct answer might deal with [wifi sniffers](http://www.ambitwire.com/wifisniffers.html), but I'd love to see what other clever answers people come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is possible to an extent. Cisco wireless APs (and likely other major enterprise vendors) can show you rogue APs and clients within broadcasting range and can even spoof disassociation packets to those rogues to keep them from functioning until they can be removed from the network.

Can a $50 Linksys do this? No, not without some alternative homebrewed firmware. Can an enterprise wireless solution do this out of the box? Absolutely.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you confirm that this would detect devices (lets say iPhones) that are within broadcasting range, even when they are not connected? "until they can be removed from the network." suggests that they are connected.

Comment: They need to be connected to *something* or probing your wifi (which would normally happen when wifi is on but not connected on the device). These features aren't normally used for statistic collection, but rather to stop rogue wireless networks from popping up in secured areas. That's what my example was about. If you have a very specific need, I suggest you call a Cisco (or Aruba) wireless VAR and ask them which of their products will meet your need. From a technical standpoint, it is possible, but your use case is uncommon.

Comment: I'll read a bit more about that and accept your answer when I'm satisfied.. I would like to up-vote but I don't have those privileges yet. Thanks